# Conditional to check if a variable is not equal to any number in a set

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

Simple question: what's a more compact way to write a conditional like the following:

```
if ($i != 8 && $i != 19 && $i != 23 && $i != 43) ...
```

I tried the following approaches with no luck:

```
if  ($i != 8 || 19 || 23 || 43) ...

if ($i != 8 or 19 or 23 or 43) ...
```

Comment: If you really need it to be short, try putting all the numbers in an array, and then check if `$i` is in that array. The examples you tried in the second part of your question are not valid syntax for comparing a single variable to multiple values. Those will always return true, because the numbers evaluate to true, rather than being compared to `$i`

Comment: hi Ben321, hope my answer will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this just make array of numbers like bellow

```
$num = array(8,19,23,43);
```

and check **in_array**  like bellow.

```
<?php
$num = array(8,19,23,43);

if(!in_array($i,$num)){
echo "here";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could collect all of those numbers into an array

```
$set = array(8, 19, 23, 43);
```

And then test the value against the set using the in_array() function

```
if (in_array($i, $set)) { ... }
```